# Percentage height within flex child causing overflow

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a responsive card component with a header that is a percentage of the overall card height and which resides within a stretched flex child. If I use a percentage value for the height of the header it causes an overflow.

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* Grid */

.recipe-grid {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-top: -1%;
}

.recipe-grid__cell {
    margin: 1%;
    min-width: 300px;
    width: 31%;
}

/* Recipe Card */

.recipe-card {
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.recipe-card__header {
    background-color: beige;
    height: 35%;
    /* height: 131px; */ /* works */
}

.recipe-card__title {
    padding: 6px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="recipe-grid">
    <div class="recipe-grid__cell">
        <div class="recipe-card">
            <div class="recipe-card__header"></div>
            <div class="recipe-card__body">
                <div class="recipe-card__title">
                    <h3 class="recipe-card__heading">
                        This is a post title
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="recipe-card__content">
                    Morbi tincidunt nulla neque, et viverra sapien consectetur sit amet. Nunc auctor, purus non iaculis interdum, mauris velit mattis ante, eget efficitur nibh ante nec nulla. Pellentesque consectetur erat ut fringilla finibus. Nunc ullamcorper semper sollicitudin. Donec scelerisque elit sit amet lectus imperdiet aliquet. Curabitur fringilla non augue in rhoncus. Integer lacus magna, aliquet vitae felis quis, molestie facilisis justo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras imperdiet eget metus tempus lacinia.
                </div>
                <a class="recipe-card__button" href="#">
                    Read More
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="recipe-grid__cell">
        <div class="recipe-card">
            <div class="recipe-card__header"></div>
            <div class="recipe-card__body">
                <div class="recipe-card__title">
                    <h3 class="recipe-card__heading">
                        This is a longer post title that is multiple lines
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="recipe-card__content">
                    Morbi tincidunt nulla neque, et viverra sapien consectetur sit amet. Nunc auctor, purus non iaculis interdum, mauris velit mattis ante, eget efficitur nibh ante nec nulla. Pellentesque consectetur erat ut fringilla finibus. Nunc ullamcorper semper sollicitudin. Donec scelerisque elit sit amet lectus imperdiet aliquet. Curabitur fringilla non augue in rhoncus. Integer lacus magna, aliquet vitae felis quis, molestie facilisis justo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras imperdiet eget metus tempus lacinia.
                </div>
                <a class="recipe-card__button" href="#">
                    Read More
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="recipe-grid__cell">
        <div class="recipe-card">
            <div class="recipe-card__header"></div>
            <div class="recipe-card__body">
                <div class="recipe-card__title">
                    <h3 class="recipe-card__heading">
                        This is a post title
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="recipe-card__content">
                    Morbi tincidunt nulla neque, et viverra sapien consectetur sit amet. Nunc auctor, purus non iaculis interdum, mauris velit mattis ante, eget efficitur nibh ante nec nulla. Pellentesque consectetur erat ut fringilla finibus. Nunc ullamcorper semper sollicitudin. Donec scelerisque elit sit amet lectus imperdiet aliquet. Curabitur fringilla non augue in rhoncus. Integer lacus magna, aliquet vitae felis quis, molestie facilisis justo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Cras imperdiet eget metus tempus lacinia.
                </div>
                <a class="recipe-card__button" href="#">
                    Read More
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Example JSFiddle here -- Best viewed with the bottom results layout](https://jsfiddle.net/sde3yqor/)

**Result**
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0sov.png)

**Expected**
[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXcKF.png)

Is it possible to have the header be a percentage of the overall card height without causing an overflow, and while having the flex children all remaining equal height?

**Edit**

It appears that using `padding-top` instead of `height` with a percentage value cause the card and flex child to resize properly and the contents no longer overflow. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/qw38gnke/)

Comment: try min-height: 30% on recipe-card_header

Comment: the problem you have is you have a fixed height so whatever is inside it, if it overflows, it goes over the boundary, you can use overflow-y to tweak it

Comment: @jorge-guerreiro If I get rid of the percentage height on the card and use Flexbox all the way down, the content still overflows. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/f9413t8a/5/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ If you have managed to resolve your problem (as your update implies) you might want to actually answer the post with your updated information _ Doing so will not only benefit your status in the SO community but perhaps more importantly,  it will benefit other visitors seeking to resolve the same issue ; )

Answer (score 0):

Use `height: 100vh;` instead of `height: 100%;` and     `overflow-y: auto;`

```css
.recipe-grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: -1%;
}

.recipe-grid__cell {
  margin: 1%;
  min-width: 300px;
  width: 31%;
}


/* Recipe Card */

.recipe-card {
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.recipe-card__header {
  background-color: beige;
  height: 35%;
  /* height: 131px; */
  /* works */
}

.recipe-card__title {
  padding: 6px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="recipe-grid">
  <div class="recipe-grid__cell">
    <div class="recipe-card">
      <div class="recipe-card__header"></div>
      <div class="recipe-card__body">
        <div class="recipe-card__title">
          <h3 class="recipe-card__heading">
            This is a post title
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="recipe-card__content">
          Morbi tincidunt nulla neque, et viverra sapien consectetur sit amet. Nunc auctor, purus non iaculis interdum, mauris velit mattis ante, eget efficitur nibh ante nec nulla. Pellentesque consectetur erat ut fringilla finibus. Nunc ullamcorper semper sollicitudin.
          Donec scelerisque elit sit amet lectus imperdiet aliquet. Curabitur fringilla non augue in rhoncus. Integer lacus magna, aliquet vitae felis quis, molestie facilisis justo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
          fames ac turpis egestas. Cras imperdiet eget metus tempus lacinia.
        </div>
        <a class="recipe-card__button" href="#">
                    Read More
                </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="recipe-grid__cell">
    <div class="recipe-card">
      <div class="recipe-card__header"></div>
      <div class="recipe-card__body">
        <div class="recipe-card__title">
          <h3 class="recipe-card__heading">
            This is a longer post title that is multiple lines
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="recipe-card__content">
          Morbi tincidunt nulla neque, et viverra sapien consectetur sit amet. Nunc auctor, purus non iaculis interdum, mauris velit mattis ante, eget efficitur nibh ante nec nulla. Pellentesque consectetur erat ut fringilla finibus. Nunc ullamcorper semper sollicitudin.
          Donec scelerisque elit sit amet lectus imperdiet aliquet. Curabitur fringilla non augue in rhoncus. Integer lacus magna, aliquet vitae felis quis, molestie facilisis justo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
          fames ac turpis egestas. Cras imperdiet eget metus tempus lacinia.
        </div>
        <a class="recipe-card__button" href="#">
                    Read More
                </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="recipe-grid__cell">
    <div class="recipe-card">
      <div class="recipe-card__header"></div>
      <div class="recipe-card__body">
        <div class="recipe-card__title">
          <h3 class="recipe-card__heading">
            This is a post title
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="recipe-card__content">
          Morbi tincidunt nulla neque, et viverra sapien consectetur sit amet. Nunc auctor, purus non iaculis interdum, mauris velit mattis ante, eget efficitur nibh ante nec nulla. Pellentesque consectetur erat ut fringilla finibus. Nunc ullamcorper semper sollicitudin.
          Donec scelerisque elit sit amet lectus imperdiet aliquet. Curabitur fringilla non augue in rhoncus. Integer lacus magna, aliquet vitae felis quis, molestie facilisis justo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada
          fames ac turpis egestas. Cras imperdiet eget metus tempus lacinia.
        </div>
        <a class="recipe-card__button" href="#">
                    Read More
                </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note: please check the result on fullscreen.**

Comment: Using `overflow-y: auto` will have the card scroll the overflowed contents. I'm trying to have the card resize to fit its contents and not overflow at all. Also changing `height: 100%` to `height: 100vh` will make the card 100 percent of the viewport height, which is not the desired behavior.